# Editing a specific line of a file

Tags: java, file

So, I've been reading here some posts on stackoverflow and also pages found on google, however they all only tell how to replace texts from a line to another text, or how to add at the end some text.

What I'm looking for is to change the the first line for example:
From this

LINE:         TEXT:

> 1           Hello
>
> 2           How are you?
>
> 3           Good, and you?
>
> 4           Fine!

To This:

> 1           Hello
>
> 2           Hey!
>
> 3           How are you?
>
> 4           Good, and you?
>
> 5           Fine!

So all we did was adding a new line, with Hey! and the other lines moved down.
What also would be possible to explain to my case is, how to delete a whole line and write a complete new text to it?
For example, from this:

> 1           Hello
>
> 2           Hey!
>
> 3           How are you?
>
> 4           Good, and you?
>
> 5           Fine!

To this:

> 1           Hello
>
> 2           Hey!
>
> 3           How's it going?
>
> 4           Good, and you?
>
> 5           Fine!

The main question is how to add/edit a whole line, and not only replace some words, like all the previous similar posts are covering.
Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure that you have not read all these previous similar posts insight fully.

Comment: Usually people try something and ask specific questions here.

Comment: try String.replaceAll(How are you, How's it going)

Comment: First things first: never edit a file with text content inline. Write in a new file then rename to the original.

Comment: People it is a file, containing text.

What i have already tried is with append, however this fcked the whole thing up.
What i also did was reading the text file with BufferedReader, and setting the whole text to a String, in a textArea to check if everything has been read right, there it was okay, however after adding something to the first line and saving it fcked again everything up.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a String by "Text"? If so, you cannot do this, since Strings are immutable in Java. You can only create another, modified String

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text, line by line into a String array. And from one String array you can create another (whatever manipulation you want to do).
If the text is in a file, then you could use BufferReader which can read line by line and you can manipulate as you wish before creating the resulting Array/String.